# i have error install angular and npm package

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

I delete the old version of angular and trying to install a new one after update Nodejs and get this error 
this error appears when trying to install angular

[image: ng install]

i trying to resolve by this steps and get different error

1) npm cache verify (If not running, add --force)
2) npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
3) check node --version  and ng --version
4) npm i -g @angular/cli@latest
5)  npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
5) Delete node_modules and run npm install
6) Kill all instances of terminal

error :

```
admins-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ sudo npm i -g @angular/cli@latest
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/ng
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete /usr/local/bin/ng: ../lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng symlink target is not controlled by npm /usr/local/bin
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/bin/ng
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/admin/.npm/_logs/2019-08-01T03_26_03_978Z-debug.log
admins-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ npm install
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/admin/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/admin/package.json'
npm WARN admin No description
npm WARN admin No repository field.
npm WARN admin No README data
npm WARN admin No license field.

up to date in 1.274s
found 0 vulnerabilities

admins-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ sudo npm install
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/admin/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/admin/package.json'
npm WARN admin No description
npm WARN admin No repository field.
npm WARN admin No README data
npm WARN admin No license field.

up to date in 1.199s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Comment: node version is  :  v10.16.1

Comment: npm version : 6.9.0

Comment: Are you installing as an admin? looks like you are on MAC.

Comment: i add sudo yes install it global

Comment: this error appear also when trying to clean npm cashing  / ~npm cache clean --force

Comment: Please post text, not pictures of text.

Comment: ok , i write the last error when i try with steps above

Comment: these are totally different errors one of them is solved with sudo the other certainly isn't.

Answer (score 1):

## Try:-

Add `sudo` if on Mac.

> As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data
>   extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to
>   make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead. If
>   you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command
>   with --force.

Delete current project and create one new:-
  A) `ng new PROJECTNAME`
   then,

```
1) npm cache verify (If not running, add --force)
2) npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
3) check node --version  and ng --version
4) npm i -g @angular/cli@latest
5)  npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
6) Delete node_modules and run npm install
7) Destroy all instances of terminal.
```

and,

Delete package.lock.json.

```
Create package.json by running  `npm init`, then follow step 6
```

Comment: i get error when write :  npm cache clean --force also

Comment: Try npm cache verify.

Comment: i go with this steps the error change to another , with angular npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/ng
npm ERR! code EEXIST

Comment: sudo npm install get error this :  npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/admin/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/admin/package.json'  , up to date in 1.199s
found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: Do you have package.json

Comment: package.lock.json on root admin

Comment: Is package.json, not package.lock.json there?

Comment: no such file or directory, open '/Users/admin/package.json'

Answer (score 0):

If your project is opened, then try closing vscode or whatever code editor and then try installing again.